# Tree structure with Jekyll

Tags: css, ruby, tree, jekyll, liquid

I have a soft question about jekyll. Which is, in your opinion, the best way to implement a tree structure in jekyll?

I will explain this a little further

[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NAEt.png):
[image]

In this picture we have an hypothetic tree structure (each dot is a page / post, the lines are links).

The main page is the black dot, and the posts for which jekyll is so good are the green dots essentially. But red and blue dots are inbetween; there are not so many as green dots, but there are quite a few, so an automatic system would be welcome rather than a made-by-hand one, especially if the tree grows, not only for green but also for blue and red dots. The dots with the same color have the same style but different content, so one needs also four different styles and some additional structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use permalinks
I hope this helps you
http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/

Answer (score 0):

To get a tree for pages you can loop through all pages and compare them to the current URL. Example here: https://github.com/jhvanderschee/leec/blob/master/_includes/submenu.html